# How to play HLS video in Android?

Tags: android, html, webview, stock, twitch

Here is stream video from justin.com or [twitch.tv](http://twitch.tv) this [CHANNEL](http://www.twitch.tv/synderen)
Go to [here](http://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/Dota%202/live) and choose any live stream, get from them url and add html://.../hls
in screen appears
[image]

Guys told me that:

> Android is weird in that it will not work on Android Chrome but will
> work in the stock Android browser (well, previous stock Android
> browser now that Chrome is the stock browser). It'll also work on all
> Safari browsers.

I've implemented this code

```java
stream = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
stream.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
stream.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
stream.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
stream.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
stream.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
stream.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
stream.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
stream.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
stream.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
stream.loadUrl("http://www.twitch.tv/arteezy/hls");
stream.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient 
{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**But it opens first picture from video and stop caching... it seems like WebView doesn't cache video...**
What is wrong?

**UPDATED**

after following code stream plays only 2 sec and then stops

```java
stream = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
stream.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

stream.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

stream.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

stream.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
stream.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
// mWebView.loadUrl("data/game.swf");
//mWebViewChat.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
// mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/live.swf?channel=d2l");
stream.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
final Activity MyActivity = this;
stream.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)   
    {
        MyActivity.setTitle("Loading...");
        MyActivity.setProgress(progress * 100); 
        if (progress*100 == 100){
            stream.clearFormData();
            stream.clearHistory();
            stream.clearCache(true);
        }

    }
});
stream.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);

stream.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
stream.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

stream.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
stream.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
stream.clearFormData();
stream.clearHistory();
stream.clearCache(true);

stream.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

stream.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
stream.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
stream.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);// no need I think

stream.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
stream.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
stream.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
stream.setInitialScale(1);

stream.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
stream.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

stream.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

stream.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);

stream.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
stream.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
// mWebView.loadUrl("data/game.swf");
//mWebViewChat.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
// mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/live.swf?channel=d2l");
stream.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
stream.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);

stream.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
stream.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

stream.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
stream.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
stream.clearFormData();
stream.clearHistory();
stream.clearCache(true);

stream.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
stream.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
stream.loadUrl("http://www.twitch.tv/arteezy/hls");
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me: (Android 5.1 Nexus 4)

```
public class TwitchFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container,
                         final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_twitch, null, false);

    Button buttonTwitch = (Button) root.findViewById(R.id.buttonTwitch);
    buttonTwitch.setOnClickListener(this);

    return root;
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) getView();
    assert layout != null;
    layout.removeView(v);

    WebView webView = new WebView(ESportLiveScoreApplication.getInstance());

    layout.addView(webView);

    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

    final WebChromeClient webChromeClient = new WebChromeClient();

    webView.setWebChromeClient(webChromeClient);
    webView.loadUrl("http://www.twitch.tv/h2p_gucio/hls");
}
}
```

I don't know why but it work only when i put WebView into FrameLayout :)