# Enable webview to play HLS streams from website

Tags: android, webview, http-live-streaming

I have set up a live streaming site which uses `HLS` for live streams. I was hoping that by using `webview` android users would also be able to see the streams on the website but I didn't get success. Is there a setting or library that can be added to webview to enable `HLS` streams?

My `webview` code is:

```
    webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    webview.loadUrl("http://192.168.43.140/TestSite/index.php");
```

Comment: I think exoplayer can handle that. It is library for playing videos. You should check it

Comment: thanks @VivekMishra for the response, exoplayer can be integrated with webview?

Comment: No need of webview if you use exoplayer

Comment: @VivekMishra unfortunately I do need webview as its what I use for the whole website to be viewed. Was hoping if possible exoplayer could be integrated with it so that the hls url in the <video> tag could be passed to it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473757/how-to-play-hls-video-in-android

Comment: hi @VivekMishra, unfortunately the https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20473757/how-to-play-hls-video-in-android didnt provide much help. Still getting the "Media could not be loaded either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported"

Comment: try with some other video too may be problem with that specific video

Comment: Its specifically the HLS streams that are failing (m3u8)